# How do I fix NativeScript Sidekick installation showing small, unusable privacy policy window?

Tags: installation, nativescript

I am running node v13.6.0, nativescript CLI v6.5.0, Android SDKs 26 and 28 (installed via Android Studio) and Oracle JDK 8 on Windows 10 Home. Both `%JAVA_HOME%` and `%ANDROID_HOME%` environment variables are properly set up. Even `nativescript doctor`/`tns doctor` runs successfully.

When I install NativeScript Sidekick, the installation seems to complete successfully then I get stuck on the Customer Data and Privacy window, where I assume I'm supposed to click on something like "I agree to the terms" to continue. However, the window is extremely small, unresizable and only a few lines of text are visible.

I have search in the NativeScript docs, FAQs, blogs and forums, browsed StackOverflow for questions tagged "nativescript" and searched among the SideKick FAQs, known issues and GitHub issues, but to no avail. I have found various StackOverflow questions and GitHub issues pertaining to installation woes, but none that relates to my particular scenario.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found any exact solution, but I have found a rather simple workaround for anyone that might have run into a similar situation.

The workaround is to simply click anywhere on the window, then tab through to two checkboxes which, when both selected, will activate the "Next" button.